# How do you get the width to not only extend the element to the right, but also the left?

Tags: css, width

Well the title says it all. (I can't use "left: ...;")

Comment: welcome to the stackoverflow. plz go through [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"right:" and "left:" are used for positioning. If you are setting the element absolutely there should be no issue. However if you have not explicitly set the position attribute in css then it will by default be relative and set to the top left most corner regardless of the "left:" property.

Comment: well that wasn't what I meant, when you increase the width of an element it  always extends to the right and since I am using bootstrap columns to position it I can't position it more to the right.

Comment: got it. have you tried centering the element in the parent container with "margin: 0 auto;"? Doing so would make the element centered which would allow the width to be expanded on both sides. Right now because it is already left aligned, there is no where for the element to expand to except for to the right

Comment: Well that doesn't exactly work. It splits the width in half. I was looking for a way to divide that 60em to 10em to the left and 50em to the right. You think you could help me with that?

Comment: Without any context or a jsfiddle of your code to show you it would be rather hard to 'help' you. There are a number of ways this could be done, all with different use cases. 1) Out the element into a div with proper padding or margin on each side. 2) Use asymmetrical padding on the element to create the desired effect. 3) Use asymmetrical margins to create the desired effect. There are too many visual variables without seeing code and your desired design

Comment: Here is the code and css for the div. <div id = "text-background" class = "col col-xs-offset-1" > </div> <style> #text-background{
      position: absolute;
      height: 60%;
      width: 60em;
      left: 1.5em;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      opacity: 0.60;

Comment: Sorry I messed the code up, I have it in a seperate file and I tried to edit ASAP so I messed up with the style tags, nvm that.

Comment: Why don't you just set padding-left to 1.5em?

Comment: it happens to the best of us :)